# Instalada librería pero ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, librería, python-import

He instalado una librería pero cuando lo llamo obtengo una ModuleNotFoundError

```
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from pandas->iexfinance) (2.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas->iexfinance) (1.11.0)
tensorflow 1.10.0 has requirement numpy<=1.14.5,>=1.13.3, but you'll have numpy 1.15.4 which is incompatible.
slackclient 1.3.0 has requirement requests<3.0a0,>=2.11, but you'll have requests 2.5.1 which is incompatible.
rasa-core 0.12.2 has requirement requests~=2.20, but you'll have requests 2.5.1 which is incompatible.
rasa-core-sdk 0.12.1 has requirement requests~=2.20, but you'll have requests 2.5.1 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: pandas, iexfinance
Successfully installed iexfinance-0.3.5 pandas-0.23.4
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Tests\StockPredictions>py
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from iexfinance.stocks import Stock
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'iexfinance'
```

Comment: En lugar del `pip install` que seguramente hiciste, di `python -m pip install` para asegurarte de que coge el pip que trabaja con el Python en uso.

Comment: De hecho, puede verse que para lanzar python usa `py`, y que eso lanza python 3.7.1, mientras que pip instaló en `C:\python36`. Por tanto mejor usar `py` también para instalar, con `py -m pip install`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [ModuleNotFoundError No puedo importar un módulo instalado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/404776/modulenotfounderror-no-puedo-importar-un-m%c3%b3dulo-instalado)

Comment: @RubialesAlberto Esa es una pregunta vieja  de 2 anos, hombre, ¿te especializas en desenterrar cadáveres?

Comment: No, no jaja. Es simplemente una labor, que esta bien hacer para limpiar el sitio. Cuando una pregunta se encuentra una buena respuesta, marcar el resto como duplicadas! :)